# Оптимизация Nginx и файловой системы для раздачи миллионов картинок

Tags: файлы, nginx, файловая-система, io, disk

Имеется сервер с нагрузкой примерно в 20 000 посетителей в сутки и двумя миллионами записей. Каждая запись содержит около 20 картинок. Все картинки размещаются на отдельном сервере общим объемом почти 5 ТБ. Запрос к картинке идет через RewriteRule на нужный сервер и обрабатывается уже на нем с помощью Nginx.

Нагрузки на первый сервер почти нет, а вот второй (который содержит картинки) с каждым разом начинает отвечать все медленнее, по top средняя LA достигает 6-7 (сервер имеет 8 ядер). При этом nginx процессы часто в D state.

Попытки оптимизировать конфиг ничего не дали:

**nginx.conf:**

```
sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
aio on;

access_log          off;
log_not_found       off;
server_tokens       off;
autoindex           off;
sendfile            on;
sendfile_max_chunk  1m;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
add_header          Cache-Control public;
gzip_static         on;
gzip_min_length     1000;
gzip_comp_level     2;
expires             max;
fastcgi_hide_header Set-Cookie;
```

Я использовал `blockdev --setra 65536` для оптимизации чтения с диска, это тоже не повлияло на производительность

При этом сервер картинок имеет в районе 31 GM RAM из которых используется почему то только 300 MB максимум.

Что я еще могу сделать для увеличения производительности чтения файлов картинок с этого сервера?

Comment: Поменять диск на более производительный, наверное?

Comment: Для таких объемов SSD например будет слишком дорогим

Comment: Ну значит терпите физические ограничения HDD ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Я уверен что ограничения здесь не из-за диска HDD а из-за моей неправильной настройки.

Comment: Ну, по описанным здесь симптомам (особенно D state) можно сделать вывод, что упор идёт именно в HDD

Comment: Ну или возможно имеет смысл хотя бы поставить несколько HDD, чтобы распараллелить нагрузку по нескольким устройствам. Или сразу RAID-массив какой-нибудь

Comment: Скорее всего это и будет моим решением. Но до этого хотелось бы поиграть с надстройками. Например aio threads, либо каким-нибудь кешированием частых путей файлов. Мне не совсем понятно почему для этих целей Nginx уже не использует память, она не используется даже на процент. И правильно ли будет копать в эту сторону, может и правда я упираюсь в физический лимит.

Comment: Вся свободная память автоматически используется системой (не nginx'ом!) под файловый кэш, поэтому здесь ничего делать не нужно. Разве что в мониторинге памяти (free, top, htop) посмотреть, что вся свободная память действительно используется под кэш

Comment: Но если у вас выкачивают очень много разных картинок, то даже 32ГБ может оказаться слишком мало для снятия нагрузки с диска - все нужные картинки могут банально не влезть в кэш

Comment: В том то и дело что свободная память почти вся. Куда копать чтобы проверить, что система вообще использует кеш хотя бы частично?

Comment: Вывод `free -m` смотрите например, там есть столбец который так и называется buff/cache

Comment: А впрочем я могу оказаться неправ и наверное стоит сперва проверить нагрузку на HDD например командой `iostat -dx` (если столбец %util упирается в 99-100 то всё плохо)